Как получить ВСЕ ip адреса сайта и положить их в bat файл?
Как получить ВСЕ ip адреса сайта и положить их в bat файл? Нужно для роутера Keenetic, но, например, у YouTube их десятки, тем более в интернете нет полностью готовых bat файлов со всеми адресами, поэтому, как это сделать(если нужен язык программирования - любой, командная строка тоже подойдёт и т.д., то есть любой рабочий способ)
Нужно что нибудь наподобие такого:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z_JYlVx8bRCs2KPoo05nEMqs0GqkIuEj/view?usp=drivesdk(Но здесь не все ip, поэтому и возник вопрос)

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

https://www.gstatic.com/ipranges/goog.json - видимо это вам нужно. Отсюда https://support.google.com/a/answer/10026322?hl=ru

Обычно у сайта есть доменное имя (например youtube.com), чтобы узнать ip адрес по доменному имени, нужно обратиться к DNS (от англ. Domain Name System — система доменных имён) — это интернет-сервис, распределённая база данных иерархической системы имён узлов сети Интернет.
Нужно открыть командную строку (в Windows) и выполнить команду:
nslookup youtube.com


 dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Не заслуживающий доверия ответ:
:     youtube.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4010:c0e::88
          2a00:1450:4010:c0e::5b
          2a00:1450:4010:c0e::be
          2a00:1450:4010:c0e::5d
          74.125.131.93
          74.125.131.91
          74.125.131.136
          74.125.131.190


Вряд ли ему нужен именно этот домен. Скорее все подсети которые нужно забить в 3 буквы чтобы ютуб работал

@vitidev Пусть уточнит в вопросе, я так его понял, про batch файл не совсем понятно, туда скрипты пишут, а не адреса.

@vitidev и Oopss, Наподобие такого https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Z_JYlVx8bRCs2KPoo05nEMqs0GqkIuEj/view?usp=drivesdk(Но здесь не все ip, поэтому и возник вопрос)

@vitidev и Oopss, Я написал, что мне нужно
